# Kafka connect custom transforms to convert schema-less Json to Avro

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to build a system that reads json data(schema-less) from Kafka, converts it to avro and pushes it to s3.

I have been able to achieve the json to avro conversion using KStreams and KSQL. I was wondering if the same thing is possible using Kafka Connect's custom transforms.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public class JsontoAvroConverter<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {

    public static final String OVERVIEW_DOC = "Transform Payload to Custom Format";
    private static final String PURPOSE = "transforming payload";
    public static final ConfigDef CONFIG_DEF = new ConfigDef();
    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> props) {
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return CONFIG_DEF;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(R record) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("acks", "1");
        properties.setProperty("retries", "10");

        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");

        avro_Schema updatedSchema = makeUpdatedSchema();

        return newRecord(record, updatedSchema);
    }

    private avro_Schema makeUpdatedSchema() {
        avro_Schema.Builder avro_record = avro_Schema.newBuilder()
                .setName("test")
                .setTry$(1);

        return avro_record.build();
    }

    protected Object operatingValue(R record) {
        return record.value();
    }

    protected R newRecord(R record, avro_Schema updatedSchema) {
        return record.newRecord(record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(), record.keySchema(), record.key(), updatedSchema, record.value(), record.timestamp());
    }
}
```

Where avro_schema is the name of my schema specified in an avsc file.

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, but the problem I am facing is that when the newRecord() function is being called, it expects updatedSchema to be of Schema type, but I'm providing it a custom avro_Schema type.

Also, the avro_record.build() that i'm saving into updatedSchema is not really the schema but the transformed record, itself. But I cannot pass just the record topic, key(=null) and the updatedRecord to the newRecord function. It expects schema and values separately.

My questions are:

1. Is it even possible to convert json to avro using KafkaConnect and without KStreams or KSQL? - because both alternatives require an independent service to be setup.
2. How do I just pass a custom avro schema to the newRecord function and then provide the data separately.

My apologies if this has already been answered, I did go through some other questions but none of them seemed to answer my doubts. Let me know if you need any other details. Thank you!

Comment: Your transformer code would need to know the exact format of the JSON in order to convert any of it into Avro. That being said, you should be able to use the exact same code from your kstreams method, and you don't need any properties object that sets up producer properties or the schema registry

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks! Do you have any examples I could refer? I understand your point, and I am able to build a schema for the json. The problem is how do I convert it to Avro. I did try to use the KStreams code, but as I mentioned, the problem here is that the inbuilt newRecord function that Kafka Connect provides expects a Schema and not a custom Schema. And there's is also the problem of what serializer-deserializer and s3 storage format to specify because KConnect is reading json and writing avro.

Comment: If I create a Schema with type, namespace, name and fields keys and create a json using this schema, would just adding format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat do the trick?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't have an example. My point was mostly that you wouldn't be able to have some generic transform function for any arbitrary JSON, and if the input data changes, the schema would break as well. I do not recognize this `avro_Schema` class you have; the Schema class that comes with Kafka Connect is what you should be building (changing `record.valueSchema()`), then the AvroFormat class takes that object and converts/writes to Avro objects

Comment: You mentioned that you were already using ksql? And you cannot deploy that in place of connect? Or you already have a running connect cluster?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I was able to set it up. We want to avoid using and maintaining additional services so we wanted to implement it using Kafka Connect as we'd need it to send Kafka messages to S3.

Comment: KsqlDB can write to S3 as well via embedded connectors. https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/use-connector-management/#embedded-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KafkaConnect custom transformer only needs to add a schema to the incoming JSON. The sink property format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat will take care of the rest.

Without a schema, the record value is a Map and with a schema it becomes a struct. I had to modify my code as below:

```
    @Override
    public R apply(R record) {
        final Map<String,?> value = requireMap(record.value(),PURPOSE);
        Schema updatedSchema = makeUpdatedSchema();

        final Struct updatedValue = new Struct(updatedSchema);


        for (Field field : updatedSchema.fields()) {

            updatedValue.put(field.name(), value.get(field.name()));
        }


        return newRecord(record, updatedSchema, updatedValue);
    }

    private Schema makeUpdatedSchema() {
        final SchemaBuilder builder = SchemaBuilder.struct()
                .name("json_schema")
                .field("name",Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
                .field("try",Schema.INT64_SCHEMA);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Thanks @OneCricketeer for clarifying my doubts!